# What is "one flat movement" of a screw on the fuel control unit?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

I'm looking to do a N1 low idle speed adjustment oa King Air B350 with the PT6A-60A engine. There is a note saying that one flat movement of the low idle speed screw in the FCU increases N1 by 3.5%

What is "one flat movement" in this context?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Which aircraft are you asking about, and do you have a picture or exact quote of the note?

Comment: I'm not a mechanic, but I'm guessing that it means that you are turning the adjustment screw with a flat headed screwdriver, in which case it would be 180 degrees (turning the "flat" part over).

Comment: The aircraft is king air b350 engine pt6a-60a there are 2 screw in one line request to loosen one screw and tighten the other to increase or decrease the n1

Comment: The note mentioned that the one flat movement of the screw increasing the n1 by 3.5%

Comment: Consider a nut or a bolt with a hexagonal shape. It has six flats in three parallel pairs. Turning one of these nuts or bolts by one flat would thus refer to turning it by one-sixth of a complete rotation, ie by 60 degrees. Other nuts and bolts, also some screws, may have other numbers of flats. A [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nut_(hardware)) page has dimensions across the flats.